# Checking solution question for radius of convergence.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I'm checking if work is correct here: find radius of convergence for these:

a) $\sum \frac{(x-1)^n}{n^2+5}$

b) $\sum \frac{3(x+2)^n}{n^n+1}$

c) $\sum \frac{(n+2)!(3x)^n}{4 (5)^n+3^n}$

d) $\sum\frac{n^4 (2x+5)^n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}$

So these all from $1$ to $\infty$. I make the test for radius of convergence $\lim{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$, and the answers I have:

a) $L=0$

b) $L=0$

c) $L=\frac{83}{5}$ (but it might be wrong)

d) $L=1$

If $L=0$, then it's all infinity. So a, b is infinity for radius of convergence. For c), is $\frac{5}{83}$? I can't know if my limit is correct for c). For d), the radius is 1.

Comment: Can someone check answers? It's one day now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c) Writing $(3x)^n=3^{n}x^{n}$ we have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+3)!3^{n+1}}{4 (5)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}} \frac{4 (5)^{n}+3^{n}}{(n+2)!3^{n}}
=3(n+3) \frac{4+(0.6)^n}{20+3 (0.6)^n} \to \infty $$
hence radius of convergence is $0$.

Comment: Note, for the other examples I'm getting as radius R of convergence
a) $R=1$, b) $R=\infty$ d) $R=\frac{1}{2}$